# How would I refactor this code to use procs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The original code:

```
  def self.user_admin_links
    ADMIN_PAGES.inject([]) do |result, page|
      result << Page.new(controller: page[:name]) if page[:menu] && (page[:group_admin] || page[:company_admin])
      result
    end
  end

  def self.super_admin_links
    ADMIN_PAGES.inject([]) do |result, page|
      result << Page.new(controller: page[:name]) if page[:super_admin]
      result
    end
  end
```

I tried to refactor like this:

```
array_builder = Proc.new do |conditional|
    ADMIN_PAGES.inject([]) do |result, page|
      result << Page.new(controller: page[:name]) if conditional
      result
    end
  end

  def self.user_admin_links
    array_builder.call(page[:menu] && (page[:group_admin] || page[:company_admin]))
  end

  def self.super_admin_links
    array_builder.call(page[:super_admin])
  end
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: undefined local variable or method `array_builder' for Page:Class.
```

When I turned array_builder into a class method, like this:

```
  def self.array_builder 
    Proc.new do |conditional|
      ADMIN_PAGES.inject([]) do |result, hsh|
        result << Page.new(controller: hsh[:name]) if conditional
        result
      end
    end
  end
```

I got an error that in the self.user_admin_links method that "page" is not recognized.

Comment: This seems like an abuse of Ruby :). There has to be a more elegant approach. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: you are trying to abstract, which is good, but you are doing it the wrong way. That inject-thing you are doing is in fact emulating a list-comprehension, that's what you have to abstract. Search questions regarding list-comprehensions in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, methods are not closures. I.e., they cannot use local variables from the surrounding scope, such as `array_builder`.

And if you want `page` to be evaluated for every element of `ADMIN_PAGES`, you should use a block argument (which is basically just some syntax for passing procs as arguments). Otherwise it is just evaluated once in the `links` methods, where `page` is not defined.

```
def array_builder &conditional
  ADMIN_PAGES.inject([]) do |result, page|
    result << Page.new(controller: page[:name]) if conditional[page]
    result
  end
end
```

Also, here is a better Ruby idiom for the job. Instead of manually pushing to an array and using inject, use `Enumerable#select` and `Enumerable#map`:

```
def array_builder &conditional
  ADMIN_PAGES.select(&conditional).map {|page| Page.new(controller: page[:name])}
end
```

The other methods then pass a block:

```
def self.user_admin_links
  array_builder {|page| page[:menu] && (page[:group_admin] || page[:company_admin])}
end

def self.super_admin_links
  array_builder {|page| page[:super_admin]}
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the detail you used here very much.  Thanks.